# Matlab's cellfun doesn't perform calls to function func in a specific order?

Tags: matlab

Matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) says:

```
[A1,...,Am] = cellfun(func,C1,...,Cn)
```

> Output arrays `A1,...,Am,` where `m` is the number of outputs from function func, contain the combined outputs from the function calls.  The ith iteration corresponds to the syntax `[A1(i),...,Am(i)] = func(C1{i},...,Cn{i})`. The cellfun function does not perform the calls to function func in a specific order.

Isn't this problematic if the order of the cells in the cell arrays is actually meaningful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is respected in that `A1(i) = func(C1{i})`. However, the relative ordering of that calls and assignments is not necessarily sequential. That is, Matlab can do

```
A1(3) = func(C1{3});
A1(5) = func(C1{5});
A1(1) = func(C1{1});
% and so on until all indices in 1:length(C1) are covered
```

The documentation is just telling you not to assume/rely on calls occurring in linear sequential order, e.g. with calls to I/O routines, references to global/persistent variables and other such devices.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes a lot more sense.